# Looking for a way to avoid getting banned while crawling

Tags: python-3.x, request, instagram

I'm doing quite a lot of requests to the page `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/some_hashtag/?__a=1` in Python. Here's the code:

```
def LoadUserAgents(uafile):
    """
    uafile : string
        path to text file of user agents, one per line
    """
    uas = []
with open(uafile, 'rb') as uaf:
    for ua in uaf.readlines():
        if ua:
            uas.append(ua.strip())
random.shuffle(uas)
return uas

address = f'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{hashtag[1:]}/?__a=1'
uas = LoadUserAgents("user-agents.txt")
ua = random.choice(uas)
headers = {
    "Connection" : "close",  
    "User-Agent" : ua}

r = requests.get(address, proxies=proxy, timeout=30, headers=headers)
```

The text file 'user-agents.txt' is from [here](https://github.com/cvandeplas/pystemon/blob/master/user-agents.txt)

An example of the variable `proxy` is `proxy={'http': 'http://104.196.45.252:80'}`

And still I can see in the logs that I'm getting banned for a short time regularly.

```
{'message': 'Please wait a few minutes before you try again.', 'status': 'fail'}
```

After such a ban I change the proxy and the user agent immediately, but the following request also shows that I'm banned.

```
[Crawler @ 17_07_2018_15h29m34s] 
Error message:{'message': 'Please wait a few minutes before you try again.', 'status': 'fail'} 
Proxy:{'http': 'http://104.196.45.252:80'}
Header: {'Connection': 'close', 'User-Agent': b'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; fr; rv:1.8.1.9pre) Gecko/20071102 Firefox/2.0.0.9 Navigator/9.0.0.3'}

[Crawler @ 17_07_2018_15h29m44s]
Error message: {'message': 'Please wait a few minutes before you try again.', 'status': 'fail'} 
Proxy:{'http': 'http://52.77.242.220:80'} 
Header: {'Connection': 'close', 'User-Agent': b'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; es-ES; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20040910'}

....
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what else I should add there to avoid the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: There are much more sophisticated ways to detect if you are the same person than some ip or user agent... like canvas fingerprinting or when it's not available other fingerprinting methods... what can you do? from python... nothing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try providing a proxy for https traffic - at the moment the proxy you are providing isn't being used.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm not sure I understood you correcly. Do you mean that 'http' proxy could not be used for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know why I've been downvoted without any comments. In any case, you are trying to connect to an https URL and providing a proxy for http. These are not the same, so it won't be used.